# Windows Azure payment method

Tags: azure, payment

I would like go through a Windows Azure trial.
But the site does not accept my payment method.

I tried with a prepaid card (Visa) and a prepaid card (Mastercard).
Are there some problems with the prepaid cards?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming within the scope [defined by the community.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Just use your prepaid card to get some Bitcoins, use your Bitcoins to get some OKPay, use your OKPay to get some Litecoins then use your Litecoins to get some bulletproof hosting, then use your bulletproof to do some phishing, then use your phish to do some carding, then use the cards to get Azure. It's simple.

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays Windows Azure doesn't accept payments with any prepaid card!

See payment options http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0003p/

Comment: Not now a days. its habit by born of ms azure.

Comment: @LiakatHossain other options\

Answer (score 2):

I have tried Payoneer Mastercard and also Neteller plastic Mastercard they charged me $1 each time when I tried but I got error that says- we do no accept prepaid card.

So Microsoft only wants users who have credit cards from real banks. Try Amazon AWS or Digital Ocean. However when i was answered this question Digital Ocean was accepting prepaid card but now a days only AWS is open.